# Getting an error message when cloning a Zapier app

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

When I clone my production Zapier app to version 2.0.0, in order to make some changes, I get an error message stating "Internal Server Error".

I'm not receiving any other details on what might be the cause of this error.

Does anyone know what might cause this?

Thanks,

Comment: can you write into partners@zapier.com with information about the app you're cloning?

Comment: just wrote in to that address